# $f'(x)=5\cos(x)-5\sin(x)$ Find Critical Numbers

Tags: calculus

$f(x)$ was $5\sin x + 5\cos x$ :  $0$ is less or equal to $x$ and $x$ is less or equal to $2\pi$

I am stuck at $5\cos(x) - 5\sin(x) = 0$

Can I divide $5$ from both sides and cancel them out?

Then can I move $\sin$ to the right of the equal sign them divide both sides by cosine to get $\tan = 1$

I guess this is really a basic arithmetic questions since I am confused as of I am allowed to divide the binomial by $5$.

Comment: You just need to find when $\cos(x)$ is the same as $\sin(x)$. Since your equations leads to $\cos(x)=\sin(x)$

Comment: Yes you can cancel the 5.  But be careful dividing both sides by $\sin(x)$ because $\sin(x)$ can be zero.  Just handle that as a special case and you've basically got it.

Comment: There's no binomial, but you can always divide an equation by whatever constant you like if you divide both sides.

Comment: @Henrik "Binomial" sometimes (rarely) means an expression with two terms. Compare: monomial, trinomial, polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a field, as the real numbers where you are working, any element $\ne 0$ has an inverse and an identity as $A=B$ remain an identity when we multiply both sides by the same number. In your case you can multiply by the inverse of $5$ i.e. $5^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{5}$ so that you have $\dfrac{1}{5}(5 \cos x - 5 \sin x)=\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot 0$ and this gives $\cos x = \sin x$ that is verified for $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+k \pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you recommend any Calculus or Algebra books (to brush up)?

Comment: $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ is not true, since $0\le x\le 2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

based on your equation you get:$\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ which happens at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$ since $0<x<2\pi$

Comment: While it is true that $\sin x = \cos x$ when $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $x = \frac{5\pi}{4}$, it is not true that $\sin x = \cos x$ when $x = \frac{3\pi}{4}$ or when $x = \frac{7\pi}{4}$ since sine and cosine have opposite signs at those angles.

Comment: oh you're right! thanks